# How to wrap comma separated string onto new line in td cell?

Tags: html, css, razor, html-table

I've one column in a table that contains comma separated emails in each cell of that column.

So for example a cell may contain the following and cell displays email inline. Instead of breaking the second email onto a newline:

```
jdoe@gmail.com,bgates@outlook.com
```

**Question:**

How can you wrap comma separated strings onto new line in td cell?

**What I've tried:**

I can't statically set a `<br/>` between the emails as they are being read back from a database dynamically.

I did also try adding a span within the td and applying a custom CSS style `wrap-emails`. But this style doesn't display the emails stacked as expected in the cell:

CSS style:

```
span.wrap-emails { 
    word-wrap:break-word

}
```

Cell definition:

```
 <td><span class="wrap-emails">@row.Contact_Emails</span></td>
```

Comment: If you are reading them from the db, why not do a string replace server side before you output it to the screen - `@Html.Raw(row.Contact_Emails.Replace(",","<br>"))`

Comment: span is an *`inline`* element *`word-wrap`* wont work, untill you define it as *inline-block*, or for best results, as *`block`*.

Comment: Indeed, why not wrap each email in it's own div?

Comment: @Pete your suggestion works, could post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replace the commas with `br`s using the following in your razor:

```
@Html.Raw(row.Contact_Emails.Replace(",","<br>"))
```

The `Html.Raw` bit is so that it renders the `br` instead of encoding it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
span.wrap-emails { 
 display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A JQuery solution is to **dynamically** replace the `,` with the `<br>` on the content of your cells like so using:

```
var emails = $('.wrap-emails').text();
$('.wrap-emails').html(emails.replace(',', '<br>'));
```

Comment: Can i know why this javascript solution is downvoted .. when I now see the same solution given in razor code above to be upvoted ??